# Xamarin.Forms Tapped event, no bindable property

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to get a ListView that is populated from the ViewModel. Referencing StackOverflow article this should be a working solution. The article can be found here [ListView not triggering ItemTapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328181/listview-not-triggering-itemtapped).

When attempting to compile I get the following error:

```
No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "ItemTapped", or mismatching type between value and property.
```

If I remove the ItemTapped from the xaml file the project will compile and the list will populate. The end goal is to make each item in the ListView clickable that leads to the specific station.

Below is the snippets of my code

StationSelectorPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Company.Forms.Views.StationSelectorPage"
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Company.Forms.ViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:StationSelectorViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            
            <Label Text="Select Station:" />
            
            <ListView 
                x:Name="StationView" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Stations}"
                ItemTapped="{Binding OnItemTapped}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding StationName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

StationSelectorPage.xaml.cs

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class StationSelectorPage : ContentPage
    {
        
        public StationSelectorPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

StationSelectorViewModel.cs

```
public class StationSelectorViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public List<StationsModel> m_Stations;
    public List<AreasModel> m_Areas;
    public ApiConnection m_apiConnection;
    ObservableCollection<StationsModel> stations = new ObservableCollection<StationsModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<StationsModel> Stations { get { return stations; }}


    public StationSelectorViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Station Selector";
        m_apiConnection = new ApiConnection(Constants.Url, null, null);
        GetStations();
    }

    public async void GetStations()
    {
        string absolutePath = DependencyService.Get<IMisc>().GetAbsolutePath();

        m_Areas = await m_apiConnection.HttpGetAsync<List<AreasModel>>("misc/get-areas");

        m_Stations = 
            m_Areas.
            Select(x => new StationsModel { StationId = x.StationId, StationName = x.StationName })
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

        foreach(var station in m_Stations)
        {
            Stations.Add(new StationsModel { StationId = station.StationId, StationName = station.StationName });
        }

    }


    public async void OnItemTapped(object group, object item, int itemIndex)
    {
        var selectedItem = item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the signature of the [ItemTapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.itemtapped?view=xamarin-forms) handler is

```
void ItemTappedHandler(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs args)
```

Comment: I adjusted the function to be:`public async void OnItemTapped(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Testing");
        }`

This present me with the same error of `No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "ItemTapped", or mismatching type between value and property.`

Comment: ah, I didn't catch that.  I don't think you an bind an event handler.

Comment: You can't bind OnItemTapped event with this way. you can use [Xamarin Community Toolkit ItemTappedEventArgsConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/community-toolkit/converters/itemtappedeventargsconverter) This [video also explains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mpe_1okwxk) how to use it in a good way.